# Creating the game Rush Hour, but having issues with the error checker. (C)

Tags: c

I am trying to create the game called Rush Hour in text through C. I am currently running into issues where my moved car is overriding other cars in the row. Currently I am coding it through a 1d array. I am not the most comfortable with a 2-d array so that is why I have no approached it through that method and stuck with one d so far.

```
void moveCar (char car, char direction, int distance)
{
    if ( car== 'g' && direction == 'r' && distance >= 0 && board[i] != '.')
    {
        int i;
        for(i=63; i>=0; i--)
        {
                if(board[i]=='G')
                {
                    board[i + distance] = board[i];
                    board[i] = '.';
                }   

        }
    }
```

That is the code currently. the board[i] !='.' is floating around many areas to test as a error checker, but failing.

Comment: One thing to think about, what if `i + distance` is larger than the number of elements allocated for `board`?

Comment: As for your problem, is it with this piece of code you show? When you say "but failing", what do you mean by that?

Comment: Are `board[]` and `i` global? If they are maybe change your local `i` variable for visibility purpose?

Comment: Yes the board is global, when i mention that it is failing I mean that when the code runs to check if the characters in front is a . or not. If it isn't then it would break out otherwise keep going.

Comment: You'll have to provide moar informations if you really want us to be able to help you sorting this out, like an error log? This is runtime error right? Check that `board[i + distance]` isn't outside of `board[]` boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `int i` before your `if` condition if you want to test `board[i] != '.'`. Your declaration must preceed the usage.

I'm also assuming that `char board[]` is a global. If it's not then there is also a problem here.

Then check if `board[i + distance]` isn't outside of `int board[]` boundaries. Since you get distance from parameters you can send anything, and you are just checking that he is `>= 0`.

Comment: If you have two `i` variables, one local and one global then just ignore this. If so then consider my commentary above.